# Handlebars get access to data in script tag

Tags: handlebars.js

I've got a plain handlebars template that I'm passing through puppeteer to generate a pdf. I'm able to access the data through the body normally but can't seem to do so in a JS script tag. My data looks something like this.

```
const context = { data: [ {..some data}, {...some data}, {...some data}] }
```

I'm trying to access it in my script tag like

```
const data = "{{ data }}"
```

but all I get back when I console log this in my script tag is

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

When I check the typeof, it comes back as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by making a simple helper to stringify the data. (I have my helpers in a helper object)

```
json: function(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  }
```

Then in my JS script I just call it with the triple brackets

```
const wedges = {{{ json data }}}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. 
I was trying to implement CanvasJS in a NodeJS app, also to generate a pdf with puppeteer. For future people, the const wedges = {{{ json data }}}; was been marked as an error on my project, but it compiled and worked great.