# json.parse not working with template engine handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, templates

I have a search box which I wish to use to populate my table so i want to access the data sent to the view template in the script tag

**ERROR IN SCRIPT**

```
1 Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at 1:164:25
```

```
<div class="FieldElement2" style="margin-top: 3%;">
    <div class="input-field ">
        <input id="search_masterTable" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>

        <table class="highlight centered responsive-table" style="width: min-content;" >
            <thead>
                <tr>                    
                <th></th>
                <th>Ledg.No.</th>
                <th>File No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="searchResultsBody">
            {{#each accounts_array}}
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="viewButton">View Chart</button></td>
                    <td class="Ledg_No" scope="row">{{ledger_num}}</td>
                    <td class="File_Num" scope="row">{{file_num}}</td>
                    <td class="Name">{{client_name}}</td>
                    <td class="gPhoneNumber3">{{phone_number6}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>

<script>

  document.getElementById('search_masterTable').addEventListener('input',()=>{

    const search_value = document.getElementById('search_masterTable').value.toUpperCase().split(' ')
    // NOT WOKING
    const data = JSON.parse("{{accounts_array}}")

    const result_array = data.filter(function(r){
      return search_value.every(function(word){
        console.log(word)
        return column_name_array.some(function(colIndex){
          console.log(r[colIndex])
          if(r[colIndex] == null){
            return false
          }else{
            return r[colIndex].toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(word) !== -1
          }                            
        });
      });
    })

    function to_populate_masterTable(){
}

</script>
```

insted of sending the search value back to the server i want to perfom the search opearation in the frontend and send display the result for every search input

**BACK END**

```
router.get('/masterTable/:id', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {

    const title = 'Master Table'
    var account = parseInt(req.params.id) 
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM mt_`+account+``, async (err,accounts_array) => {

        res.render('masterTable', {
            accounts_array,
            title
        })

    })
})
```

**THIS IS WHAT THE account_array LOOKS LIKE**

```
[
  RowDataPacket { // <= this is the error
    id: 1,
    ledger_num: 'VM364',
    file_num: 'VM364',
    client_name: 'MUTHU KUMAR',
    phone_number1: '9791716460',
    status: 'UNSETTLED'
  },  
RowDataPacket {
id: 1,
.,
.,
.,
},
RowDataPacket {},
RowDataPacket {}
]
```

**error that i got**

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at 1:169:21)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass data from node.js to local javascript, keeping array capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740539/how-to-pass-data-from-node-js-to-local-javascript-keeping-array-capabilities)

Comment: this is for ejs and not handle bars the ```const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("{{accounts_array}}"));``` doesnt work

Comment: Does `const data = {{JSON.stringify(accounts_array)}};` or `const data = {{{JSON.stringify(accounts_array)}}};` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebars get access to data in script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713235/handlebars-get-access-to-data-in-script-tag)

Comment: _"THIS IS WHAT THE account_array LOOKS LIKE"_ No, that's not how an array in JavaScript looks like. That's a textual representation. You have to serialize the array, e.g. with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Why are there two different errors in your question? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

This might work by first stringifying the variable and using the tag syntax to pass the stringified JSON to the template:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(<%= JSON.stringify(accounts_array) %>);
```

Comment: this is the syntax for ejs and not handlebars i did search but was unable to find handlebars syntax for this

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713348/6346643

Comment: i think the proble is in the data and not in the json.parse.... ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at 1:169:21)```